# Codename One: Issue with .createMedia method and audio files

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm trying to make an audio player for a game using Codename One but I've been running into issues with the .createMedia method.

```
public class AudioPlayer {
private Media MEDIA = null;
public Media media;

public void playAudio(String fileName) {
    try {
        if (MEDIA == null) {
            InputStream is = CN.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            System.out.println(is);
            MEDIA = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/wav", new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MEDIA = null;
                }
            });
        if (MEDIA != null && MEDIA.isPlaying() == false) {
            MEDIA.setVolume(100);
            MEDIA.play();
        } }
    } catch (IOException ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }
} }
```

Class where playAudio and AudioPlayer are instantiated:

```
public AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(); //audio player 
public VolumeButton volumeButton = new VolumeButton();

public Game() {
    changeState(sceneNum);
    audioPlayer.playAudio("/fluffingADuck.wav");
```

I'm almost certain it is not an issue with the file pathing as I get an address when I print out 'is' and I've used is.available() to check if there are bytes in 'is'.
I have also tried using a .mp3 instead of .wav file to no avail.
This is the stack trace that I get; the program is still able to run despite the error

```
java.io.IOException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.createMedia(JavaSEPort.java:9535)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.createMedia(Display.java:3705)
    at com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:306)
    at com.example.audio.AudioPlayer.playAudio(AudioPlayer.java:31)
    at com.example.myapp.Game.<init>(Game.java:30)
    at com.example.myapp.Game.getGame(Game.java:39)
    at com.example.myapp.MyApp.runApp(MyApp.java:14)
    at com.codename1.system.Lifecycle.start(Lifecycle.java:129)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$3$2.run(Executor.java:340)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.executeSerialCall(Display.java:1395)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1379)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1166)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Any help would mean a lot I've been stuck on making this audio player.

Comment: might be related to media format or encoding. the `createMedia` method supports a lot of formats but they won't all necessarily work on all platforms. 

i would check the exception details by modifying your `catch`:

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: This is a [wrapper exception](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/JavaSEPort.java#L9535) which is an exception that is wrapping another internal failure. When printing it to the console you would see the original exception just above it and it would include the actual problem description. Notice you can edit the question to include the additional exception.

Comment: The only thing above the stack trace is this 
Adding CEF to classpath
Retina Scale: 2.0
Adding watch folder /Users/mrducky/Documents/DuckWorldMobile/common/src/main/java
Did not find hotswap-agent.properties file
SourceChangeWatcher running.  Watching directories [/Users/mrducky/Documents/DuckWorldMobile/common/src/main/java]

Comment: Are you sure that you've put the whole stack trace in your question? There should be another exception *after* (not above) that stack trace, saying `Caused by ...`.

Comment: I am not getting anything saying "Caused by..." My program still runs just that the Exception StackTrace prints.

Answer (score 1):

The print code for the exception seems incorrect as mentioned below in the original answer but the problem isn't that.

The class `Game` is probably your main class (the one where the `start()` method is in or subclass of `Lifecycle`). You wrote the code in the constructor or alternatively within that chain.

Until the `init(Object)` method of the main class is invoked. If you initialize stuff in the constructor or static initializer then Codename One itself isn't initialized and things will fail.

To fix the stack trace fix this code:

```
catch (IOException ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }
```

To this:

```
catch (IOException ioe) { 
   if(ios.getCause() != null) {
       ios.getCause().printStackTrace();
   }
   ioe.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

This should either answer the question or provide applicable additional details. Assuming the latter, edit the question with the additional details and I'll improve this answer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3ccE2UH
I did that this is all my terminal prints. 
Maybe I should just go for another method to play sounds?

Comment: I see the problem, edited my answer

Comment: I switched up the way my program runs by using the init() method to "start" my game in the myApp class but it did not work. Something interesting I came across however was that I created a new project and tried the run the video playback program in the MediaManager API page. I got this error however:  '/Use.zip-extracted/cef/macos64/libjcef.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')). I've tried different distributions of OpenJDK recommended by the "getting started" page. Do I need to install something else differently?

Comment: I thought we solved the ARM distro problems, let me check on that.

Answer (score 1):

To play mp3 try this

```
audioPlayer.playAudio("/test.mp3");

public void playAudio(String mp3FileName) {
    try {
        Media media = MediaManager.createMedia((Display.getInstance()
                .getResourceAsStream(getClass(), mp3FileName)), "audio/mpeg");

        media.play();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Play Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

As instructed before mp3 file should be in `\common\src\main\resources` directory.

Note mimeType should be `audio/mpeg` not `audio/mp3`

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately ran into the same issue.

Comment: Works just fine for me

Comment: What about when you create a new project with only this function to playAudio()? Does mp3 file exist in resources directory? Does the filename you are passing to playAudio() match the one in resources directory?